# Как разделить лог файле Postgres Sql на части с помощью Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Нужно разделить лог файл на группы. 
Написал такое выражение `([0-9]{4}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}|([+][0-9]{2})|([\[][0-9]{2,7}[\]])|([a-zA-zа-яА-ЯЙйЁё]{1,10}:  ))`

```
2022-07-08 17:59:13.857 +06 [15908] ОПЕРАТОР:  
    UPDATE "public"."Test"
    SET
        "date_one" = $1,
        "date_two" = $2,
        "result" = $3,
        "statusId" = $4
    WHERE
        "Id" = $5
2022-07-08 17:59:13.862 +06 [6768] ОШИБКА:  INSERT или UPDATE в таблице "Test" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "FKlrvReRFTdJZNKrNkZm26QesaeQw"
2022-07-08 17:59:13.945 +06 [15908] ОПЕРАТОР:  
    UPDATE "public"."Test"
    SET
        "date_one" = $1,
        "date_two" = $2,
        "result" = $3,
        "statusId" = $4
    WHERE
        "Id" = $5
```

Данное выражение получает только первую часть: `2022-07-08 17:59:13.862 +06 [6768] ОШИБКА:`   [Ссылка на Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Bw8eww/1)

Как можно получить часть с запросом, то есть то что находиться после запятой и до след. даты и т.д.?

Сейчас получаю массив:
 `["2022-07-08 17:59:13.862","+06","[6768]","ОШИБКА: "]`
Нужно получить:
 `["2022-07-08 17:59:13.862","+06","[6768]","ОШИБКА: ", "Запрос... или описание ошибки"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

// language=regex
string pattern = @"
^
(?'date' \d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{3})
\s
(?'zone' \+\d{2})
\s
(?'code' \[\d+\])
\s
(?'type' \w+)
:\s{2}
(?'text' .+?)
(?= ^\d{4} | \Z)
";

var options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var groups = match.Groups;

    Console.WriteLine(groups["date"]);
    Console.WriteLine(groups["zone"]);
    Console.WriteLine(groups["code"]);
    Console.WriteLine(groups["type"]);
    Console.WriteLine(groups["text"]);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

`// language=regex` - включит подсветку синтаксиса и подсказки в процессе набора.

`^` - начало строки,
`(?'имя' )` - именованная группа,
`\d` - цифра,
`\w` - любая буква,
`(?= )` - позитивный просмотр вперёд: ищем начало строки и четыре цифры или конец строки.

Чтобы шаблон `.+` захватывал многострочный текст, указываем опцию `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` - добавлено для удобства написания шаблона регулярки - игнорирует пробельные символы. Поэтому настоящие пробелы нужно задавать только в виде `\s`.